# Jenkins Valgrind plugin appears to sum errors across tests

Tags: jenkins, valgrind, jenkins-plugins

I am really happy to see that a Valgrind plugin exists for Jenkins. I use it for C/C++ code at work.
I have set it up in Jenkins (Linux Ubuntu 14.04 - the valgrind plugin version 0.22) to dump xml files.

My config is like this

[image: Valgrind for Jenkins]

I can see that I do get my memcheck files out in the xml directory

```
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 1379 Oct 25 18:21 main.18996.memcheck
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 1379 Oct 25 18:22 main.19100.memcheck
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 2452 Oct 25 18:27 main.19489.memcheck
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 2453 Oct 25 18:28 main.19605.memcheck
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 2453 Oct 25 18:28 main.19692.memcheck
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 2453 Oct 25 18:28 main.19774.memcheck
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 1379 Oct 25 18:29 main.19963.memcheck
```

I can see that the memcheck files look fine with some "dirty underwear" such as

```
<error>
  <unique>0xb</unique>
  <tid>1</tid>
  <kind>InvalidWrite</kind>
  <what>Invalid write of size 4</what>
  <stack>
    <frame>
      <ip>0x80483EB</ip>
      <obj>/home/jenkins/workspace/DemoValgrind/main</obj>
      <fn>main</fn>
      <dir>/home/jenkins/workspace/DemoValgrind</dir>
      <file>main.c</file>
      <line>12</line>
    </frame>
  </stack>
  <auxwhat>Address 0x41ae21c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd</auxwhat>
</error>
```

My problem is that the Valgrind plugin counts the sum of all errors in all of the main.*.memcheck files.

I expected a view more like this one:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/60918012/valgrind-trend-graph.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1336573302000

where the number of errors go up and down.

I must be configuring the Valgrind "Publish Valgrind Results" wrongly.
Is there a syntax where I can get the overview diagram (the URL just above) to match the number of errors according to the build, i.e.
not accumulate?

Comment: Are those other memcheck files from previous runs of this job? Are you cleaning the workspace before running valgrind?

Comment: If I clean the workspace then I get the "valgrind trend" on the frontpage UI to constantly report zero errors for all tests even though the previous tests were buggy